# Run all microservices in a multi-project gradle build

Tags: gradle, microservices

I have a multi-project gradle build that's roughly set up like this:

```
RootProject
- ServiceA
- ServiceB
- ServiceC
- UI
```

Each of these subprojects is using the Spark framework and runs an embedded web server.  It's basically a microservices setup, so they all need to be up and running for the system as a whole to work.

They each have a task defined like this:

```
task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'App'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

I know I can manually start each service either through my IDE or by opening a different terminal for each sub-project and running `gradlew ServiceA:runApp`, but what I'd like to do is create a `runSystem` task at the root level that will fire up everything to make it easy to run the whole system during development.

How can I do this with Gradle?

Comment: What happens if you run `runApp` in the root project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a task on the root project, Gradle invokes the same task (if it exists) on all the subprojects. Just execute `runApp` from the root folder.

In your case however, your runApp task might not exit because it starts a server, so execution will not move on to the next project. You can either enable parallel execution, or modify your tasks to run your server tasks in the background (using `ProcessBuilder`)